# Какой дистрибутив linux выбрать для слабого ноутбука?

Tags: linux

Пользуюсь Linux mint чуть больше недели, и заметил что сама система кушает довольно много оперативной памяти, для моего стационарного ПК это ничего, но я теперь хочу поставить Linux и на свой ноутбук где всего 4 гб ram. Какой дистрибутив лучше выбрать для использования на слабом ноутбуке?

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Может DE ест много.
Поставьте в своем же Минте openbox, например, и посмотри как оно вам по ресурсам и удобству.

Comment: `Xfce - `https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/choose.html

Comment: https://distrowatch.com/search.php?category=Old+Computers#simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для слабого ноутбука хорошо подойдет Arch Linux или его производные(Manjaro, Antegros). Или же если их установка вызовет затруднения ставьте чистый Debian.

Answer (score 1):

С 4-мя ГБ многие будут работать нормально. Однако, к графической среде стоит отнестись внимательнее - именно в  ней основное потребление ОЗУ.
Ставьте [openbox](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/openbox) или другое легковесное окружение.
У меня с ним работал достаточно резво IBM ThinkPad 600x